# Fire custom notification between apps in Mule

Tags: notifications, mule, listener

Using mule community 3.7.0, is it possible to fire custom notifications from one app and register for those notifications in another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved inter-app notifications by writing a notification manager and adding a single instance of that class to the mule context of all deployed apps. To do this you need to write a mule extension which is a class that implements org.mule.MuleCoreExtension, and also implement org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentServiceAware to add the class to apps when they are initialized.

To receive the notification I wrote a custom message source that triggers a flow when a notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

As per mule's documentation, Custom Alerts and Notifications are a feature that is currently only available for applications deployed to CloudHub workers. They are not available for applications that you deploy via the Runtime Manager to local servers on-premises. Ref : https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/custom-application-alerts

Answer (score 0):

You can create topics (Virtual Topics) in ActiveMQ to publish notification messages from application and subscribe those notification from other application.